# Dynamic CSS in ember component?

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

How to pass dynamic CSS property

```
{{test-component  height=height}}
```

test-component.hbs

```
<div class="flip-container ">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            RED SIDE
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            BLUE SIDE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Suppose I want to modify this CSS property

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 10em;
    height: 20em;
}
```

I have seen `bind-attr` helper , but now it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass `class` attribute to the component.

```
{{test-component  height=height myclass=myclass }}
```

test-component.hbs

```
<div class={{myclass}}>
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front">
            RED SIDE
        </div>
        <div class="back">
            BLUE SIDE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Checkout this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4f0e69a697bf5d7e679df2401f99a4ff).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change inline css according to `height` property. If so there are to approaches:

1. You could pass dynamic values to style attribute of an element
   in template: `<div style="height: {{height}}px;"></div>` You could
   find a working example in [this
   ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2c0da8a6438816c8219597f293a423b8?openFiles=templates.application.hbs).
2. You could observe changes to `height` in your component and change CSSOM
   accordingly: `this.get('element').style.height = '10px';`

There was some arguments which one should be preferred. Some argues that template binding is easier to read and feels more like the ember-way. On the other hand it requires a `style-src: unsafe-inline` Content-Security-Policy (CSP) which modifying CSSOM does not.

Of course if possible you should always use css classes.